# How to position elements in a new line in Flow Pane layout in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, flowpane

I know that elements in Flow Pane layout in JavaFX are positioned next each other in one orientation.
I want in the middle of this process to force JavaFX to put elements in a new line , to some extend like "\n" character in print method .
How i can do this ?

Comment: `FlowPane` doesn't have that functionality. Why not put multiple `FlowPane`s in a `VBox`?

Comment: @James_D you should add this as an answer. I have not noticed your comment when looking for a solution and had to come up with it myself (which took some time)

Answer (score 2):

A blank full width node behaves like "\n" in `FlowPane`.

```
Region p = new Region();
p.setPrefSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, 0.0);
flowPane.getChildren().add(p);
```

I think this is effective in case you want to control **line breaking as a node**.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't how FlowPane works. You may be better off using a GridPane so you can specify the number of rows/columns. Or you can use a composite layout and use a FlowPane for each row, then put all your FlowPanes in a VBox.